# Iframe javascript src setting opens in entire window

Tags: iframe, window

I have defined an IFrame in HTML. 
From JavaScript I am trying to change the URL(`src` attribute) of the IFrame. It's working fine with most of the URLs. But when I try to set an eBay item URL more than once it opens in entire window.

Here is my code:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            function seturl(){
                 var txt=document.getElementsByName("txt");
                document.getElementById('testframe').src = txt[0].value;    

            }
        </script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <iframe id="testframe"  width= "700" height="500" > 
        </iframe> 
        <input type="text" name="txt" width="700"/> 
       <input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="seturl()" /> 
    </body> 

    </html>
```

Is there any solution to avoid opening in entire page for this eBay items URL?

http://cgi.ebay.com/Apple-iPad-Wi-Fi-32GB-BRAND-NEW-NO-RESERVE_W0QQitemZ220725228457QQcategoryZ171485QQcmdZViewItem

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to do so.
It would seem that what you want to do is a violation of the UA.
http://pages.ebay.com/help/policies/user-agreement.html